CSS custom cursor not moving in chrome console
I created a custom blend cursor using css and js code (followed a vid). The cursor looks how I want but it is not moving in the  chrome console.
Expected to get what I saw in the video but ended up with the code not working


let innerCursor = document.querySelector(".innercursor");
let outerCursor = document.querySelector(".outercursor");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e) {
  let x = e.clientX;
  let y = e.clientY;
  //console.log(x,y)

  innerCursor.style.left = '${x}px';
  innerCursor.style.top = '${y}px';
  outerCursor.style.left = '${x}px';
  outerCursor.style.top = '${y}px';

}
.innercursor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 1.5s;
}

.innercursor.grow {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 1.5s;
}

.outercursor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
<div class="innercursor"></div>
<div class="outercursor"></div>




"but it is not moving in the chrome console" .. what? Custom cursor wont ever be visible on the console, only the DOM\

I'm not sure if it's just a copy/paste error, but your position assignments won't work if they use single quotes like that. If you want to use interpolation you need to use backticks: \${x}px``

Thank you @jmcgriz
It seems that was the issue.

The main issue with your code is that you used the $ symbol and {} braces, which are used for template literals in JavaScript. these should be placed inside backticks (``) instead of single quotes ('').
